# Pocket CPP/NppExec : Where does it search for txt files when using ifstream

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I'm trying to use Pocket CPP to compile C++ on notepad++. I cant get it to open the text file when using ifstream though. What folder to I put the txt file so that PocketCPP/NppExec reads it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current working directory (where the txt should be located) compiling/executing the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> path(512);
    _getcwd(&path[0], path.size());
    cout << &path[0] << endl;
}
```

PS: I'm the creator of Pocket C++, you can use the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/pocketcpp/issues/list) too. I'll add an issue to change the working directory in future versions (which I think it's should be the same of the .cpp file by default).